# Firefox debugger pauses in the wrong place on errors coming from functions stored in arrays

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Let's say I have the following code:

```js
const myFunctions = [];
function callMyFunctions(v) {
    for(let func of myFunctions) {
        func(v);
    }
}

myFunctions.push((v) => {
    console.log("Foo", v);
    throw "Error!";
});

callMyFunctions(123);
```

If I run this code on Firefox with the "Pause on exceptions" box checked in the Firefox developer tools, the debugger will pause in the incorrect place. Instead of pausing on the `throw "Error!"` line, it pauses on the `func(v)` line. If I then unpause the execution, the traceback written to the console does point to the correct place, but that's much less useful than having it pause there mid-execution.

This issue does not occur if I don't store the function in an array. The following code has the debugger pausing in the correct place:

```js
let myFunction = null;
function callMyFunction(v) {
    myFunction(v);
}

myFunction = (v) => {
    console.log("Foo", v);
    throw "Error!";
}

callMyFunction(123);
```

Is there any way for me to get Firefox to pause in the correct place for errors emanating from functions stored in arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, if I access the array via its indexes rather than an iterator, the debugger works correctly.

```js
const myFunctions = [];
function callMyFunctions(v) {
    // The following two options both work correctly:
    for(let i = 0; i < myFunctions.length; i++) {
        myFunctions[i](v);
    }
    // And
    for(let i in myFunctions) {
        myFunctions[i](v);
    }
}

myFunctions.push((v) => {
    console.log("Foo", v);
    throw "Error!";
});

callMyFunctions(123);
```